# Avoid objmsg function overhead?

Tags: objective-c

Can we avoid objmsg function overhead by using sel and imp means selector and implementation pointer.Please tell how we can avoid it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// first, access the SELector you're interested in (example)
SEL sel = @selector(<#SOMETHING#>);

// this is the definition of IMP
id (*IMP)(id, SEL, ...);
```

access the IMP for an instance of a specific class using:
 `+ (IMP)instanceMethodForSelector:(SEL)aSelector;`

ideally, you will cast the result of instanceMethodForSelector: to an **exact** typedef of the function you call so the compiler can get the sig right.

once you have the object, SEL and IMP, then use the IMP as an ordinary C function pointer.

where the first message to the IMP function returned is the object(=`self`), and the second argument is the selector(=`_cmd`). these are the 2 hidden objc arguments.

Comment: In the olden days (10.3 / 10.4) I was able to speed up a time-consuming data search by a factor of... well, a lot. Let us know the numbers if you implement this.

Comment: i've dug up an interesting article (with test) on the subject: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/performance-comparisons-of-common-operations-leopard-edition.html IMP-caching was (in Leopard) 7 times faster than objc_msgSend, while c++ *dynamic* dispatch was 1.5 slower than imp caching. of course, static dispatch in c or c++ should be equal or better than imp caching (assuming it's not been inlined). i remember defending somebody on the cocoa lists for wanting to use C to avoid overhead (in the olden days). in that conversation, 'if objc_msgSend shows up in profiling...' came up (cont)

Comment: (cont) while many of the points i made in that discussion were that function/method calls could be omitted entirely... well, objc_msgSend (sum, including variants) can sit around 2% to 7% of execution times in profiles of gui programs which are written mostly in c++. in the context of the execution, that equates to a 'fairly warm spot' -- if your app must be optimal, then objc's use of dynamism and its runtime is quite restricting. as well, it should not used in realtime contexts (e.g. audio). in short, there's a lot to gain (wrt performance) if you use c or c++ instead of objc.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you requirement is a result of profiling, and not a case of premature optimization.

1) You can fetch method's implementation (see Justin's answer). To elaborate - there is no much overhead in `objc_msgSend`. Most of the time it will check for `nil` value of `self`, search for IMP in cache and perform a tail call to IMP ( http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/12/18/objc_msgsend-part-1-the-road-map/ ). If you want to save this few instructions then ...

2) ... write your function in C from the start. It is much more readable and reliable solution.

Answer (score 1):

The only serious answer to this question is

> Use something other than Objective-C

Honestly, any way to avoid `obj_msg_send()` is guaranteed to be fragile and will probably save you nanoseconds per call.  If you do have a very short function that is called very frequently, then you should probably just use C to reimplement that function.  In almost all other cases, it's not worth the bother.

Comment: Getting the method implementation and calling it directly is official documented and legal API according to Apple, so there is absolutely nothing fragile about it. It's the same thing obj_msg_send() does internal. And saving 1 ns per Call for an operation called 1 Mio time saves you 1 ms, which can be critical, if you do things like animations and you want to 60 FPS (which means you only have 16.6 ms to calculate and render the next frame, so 1 ms is already 1/16th of the time you have available, you don't want to waste that for nothing).

Comment: @Mecki You are ignoring the fact that it is possible to associate different functions with a selector at run time (see, for example, key-value observation). Unless you know for sure that this will not happen, you shouldn't do it.

Comment: When KVO is used, `methodForSelector:` will still give you the correct function pointer (the one with KVO). You just must not cache the result of it beyond the scope of the current method, not unless you know for sure that there's no code that can cause the IMP to change. Apple will cache the result internally but they also correctly flush that cache when required (you can't as there is no way your code can know when it has to flush). But Apple officially recommends this method e.g. to speed up for-loops, see [here](http://t1p.de/yxjy) Look for "Getting a Method Address".

Comment: And a Obj-C method call is about 5 times slower than a C function call (13 CPU cycles), see here : https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/performance-comparisons-of-common-operations.html  But that's only because Apple does aggressive caching on IMP pointers themselves. The first time a method is called or after the caches had to be flushed, that can be much slower. Still, it means by avoiding the lookup entirely, you can make 5-times the calls and it won't affect total runtime at all. As usual, it depends on what your App is doing, for 90% of apps it probably makes no difference.